# spring integration test for the controller with post method

Tags: spring-mvc, mockmvc

I've got a controller with some parameters. It's `RequestMethod` is `POST`. But I send POST request with some parameters in URI and some in the body.

But when I write such test

```
mockMvc.perform(
            post("/")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                    .param(..uri parameter..).content(..body parameters..))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("SUCCESS"));
```

I always got `Status expected:<200> but was:<400>`.

How to write this test properly?

Comment: Some post parameters in URI? Are you sure method is POST? Not GET?

Comment: The request is syntactically incorrect. Show your mapped handler and request parameters.